# Spring adds request mappings for beans that aren't annotated with @Controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, request-mapping

I have a library that contains the DTO and service interface.

```java
@RequestMappping("/api/foo")
public interface FooApi {

   @GetMapping("/{id}")
   Foo getFooById(@pathVariable long id);

}
```

The server implements that interface:

```java
@RestController
public FooController implements FooApi {

    Foo getFooById(long id) {
         return fooService.getById(id);
    }

}
```

And I have clients that also implement that interface:

```java
@Component
public FooClient implements FooApi {

    Foo getFooById(long id) {
         return restTemplate.getObject(baseUrl + "/api/foo/{id}", ...);
    }

}
```

(in the future the client implementation will get derived from the annotations at runtime: `clientFactory.createInstance(FooApi.class)`)

Is there a way to tell Spring to not treat the `FooClient` as a Controller, because I didn't annotate it as such?
(Without removing the `@RequestMapping`s from the `FooApi` interface entirely?)

I'm using Spring-Boot 2.7.

Comment: do you place all of them into  the same module(same spring context)? The common deal is split api declaretion ,  its client and its server implement  to three modules(so there is no need to process context problem).

Comment: Why add RequestMapping to an interface, particularly when you intend to have classes implement that interface that are not expecting to serve web requests? Seems like a confusing pattern at best. You could, for instance, have a base server-side implementation class and add the common mappings there.

Comment: The idea behind using the interface is that you have the controller implement the interface and generate a client using the annotations. The annotations are on the interface to ensure that there aren't any incompatible changes between the controller and the client.

Comment: The client implementation would be done via JDK Proxies. There I have access to the method reflection and thus can analyze it what properties needs to be added where. And my colleagues and I can no longer forget about updating our service methods and no longer have to worry about typos or incorrect formatting of parameters.

Comment: The client is currently implemented in a separate package, in the future it will be generated as runtime bean. The interface is in a shared jar used by both server and client. Since the client inherits the methods, it also inherits the annotations. And since the client service is also a web service it tries to map the client methods as well.